# Gutter Width on jQuery Masonry / Isotope not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Im trying to get a Gutter Width of 10px between my Div's, but it doesn't seem to be applying. The Isotope script is working, because the items shuffle around and i have got a filtering navigation to work also.

Im just struggling to get this Gutter! :(

Heres the code:

```
    $('#main-project-grid').isotope({
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 313,
            gutterWidth: 10
        }
    });
```

And here's my HTML:

```
    <div class="container" id="main">
        <div class="container-content" id="main-grid">

            <div class="post-grid">
                Box Item
            </div>

            <div class="post-grid">
                Box Item
            </div>

            <div class="post-grid">
                Box Item
            </div>

            <div class="post-grid">
                Box Item
            </div>

            <div class="post-grid">
                Box Item
            </div>

        </div>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same problem; I made a jsfiddle to test your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/elektrorl/5W5HQ/

edit: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html#modified_layout_modes >> "Isotope’s methods can be extended and overwritten to shim-in additional functionality."

Comment: what about gutterHeight? do you have any idea how to made this?

Comment: You just have to add a bottom margin (within the CSS) on your 'post-grid' classes for a vertical gutter.

Answer (score 5):

Changing gutterWidth by "gutter" worked for me:

```
$('#main-project-grid').isotope({
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 313,
       "gutter": 10
    }
});
```

Comment: wat? unlike gutterWidth, and contrary to the masonry docs, this actually works! thanks.

Comment: Wow, can't believe this actually worked. Haven't looked at the source to see why but thanks for the tip!

**Update**: Looks like there *is* really obscure documentation on this. See `masonry: gutter` under [Element Sizing](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#element-sizing) and [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/aEmkl) for an example from the man himself.