# isotope.js masonry layout peculiarity

Tags: jquery, layout

I want to have a grid of items, and when you click one a class is appended to change its size. This works fine, except when you click the first item (top left), at which point the layout is, well, rubbish! [Here's a jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robinnicholl/FELkh/) showing the problem: click any colour to see it working nicely; click the black one to see a very un-masonry layout.

Any ideas?

JAVASCRIPT

```
    jQuery(function($){
        var $container = $('#grid');
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.tile',
            layoutMode: 'masonry'
        });
```

`$container.delegate('.tile', 'click', function(){
        $this = $(this);
        if( ! $this.hasClass('locked') ) {
            $this.addClass('clicked');
            $('.tile').each(function(){
                if( ! $(this).hasClass('clicked') ) {
                    $(this).removeClass('large');
                }
            });
            $this.removeClass('clicked');
            $this.toggleClass('large');
            $container.isotope('reLayout');
        }
    });
});
</pre>`

Answer (score 1):

Isotope and Masonry both leave gaps in many situations when your isotope items have different sizes.  The layout algorithm is just not that robust - even in situations where you COULD have a perfect masonry layout with no gaps, it often will leave gaps anyway.

The reason it only happens on the first (black) element is because isotope automatically uses the dimensions of the first element upon `layout` / `reLayout` to do its calculations.

Fortunately there is a great layout plugin for isotope called `perfectmasonry` which improves this behavior significantly and gets rid of the gaps.  **[Find it on GitHub here](https://github.com/zonear/isotope-perfectmasonry)**.

Assuming your elements are all grid sized (e.g. they are all multiples of *n* pixels) this should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried PerfectMasonry, and it doesn't make any difference at all in my situation (in fact, when I add it to my jsFiddle it causes all the tiles to stack on top of each other and be invisible; it does still function on my local instance, but doesn't improve things).

Comment: Is there any way of getting round isotope/masonry's using the first element to work out the layout?

Comment: I have a sort of hack which renders the first row of items 'hidden' (actually smaller height than the other tiles, and all white), which isn't ideal from a responsive point of view. But it would be OK if I could use something like this, but moving the element to the first position in the second row...<code>$container
    .prepend(activeElement.remove())
    .isotope('reloadItems')
    .isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' });</code>

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831313/gutter-width-on-jquery-masonry-isotope-not-working) which doesn't employ perfectMasonry but extends isotope...

```
$.Isotope.prototype._getMasonryGutterColumns = function() {
    var gutter = this.options.masonry && this.options.masonry.gutterWidth || 0;
    containerWidth = this.element.width();
    this.masonry.columnWidth = this.options.masonry && this.options.masonry.columnWidth ||
    this.$filteredAtoms.outerWidth(true) ||
    containerWidth;
    this.masonry.columnWidth += gutter;
    this.masonry.cols = Math.floor((containerWidth + gutter) / this.masonry.columnWidth);
    this.masonry.cols = Math.max(this.masonry.cols, 1);
};

$.Isotope.prototype._masonryReset = function() {
    this.masonry = {};
    this._getMasonryGutterColumns();
    var i = this.masonry.cols;
    this.masonry.colYs = [];
    while (i--) {
        this.masonry.colYs.push(0);
    }
};

$.Isotope.prototype._masonryResizeChanged = function() {
    var prevSegments = this.masonry.cols;
    this._getMasonryGutterColumns();
    return (this.masonry.cols !== prevSegments);
};
```